# .htaccess php Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem rewritting /authentication/view_profile?user=(username) to myurl.com/profil/(username)

Right now my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Rewrite /view.php?vis=id to /opslag/vis/id
#RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/(\d+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

#Rewrite authentication/view_profile.php?user=* to profil/*
RewriteRule ^profil/(\d+)$ /authentication/view_profile.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

#Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#Remove /page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I'm already using a rule to rewrite another one, which is the "#Rewrite view.php?vis=id to /opslag/vis/id

Right now my URL's look like this:

```
<a href='/profil/$_SESSION[username]'>Vis profil</a>
```

I hope you wanna help me.

If you need some details please just tell me.. :o)

Comment: It would be good to know what doesn't work. Do you get an error from the server?

Comment: @Enyo When I'm having those settings it just says: Not Found

The requested URL /profil/(username) was not found on this server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
RewriteRule ^profil/([^/]+)$ /authentication/view_profile.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Your rule can only accept usernames if they consist of digits only `(\d+)`. This one `([^/]+)` will accept any characters (except `/`, which is a folder delimiter).

**P.S.**
Consider reading this [Introduction to regular expressions and mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) if you plan to use .htaccess and URL rewrite rules on regular basis.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and thanks for the link :o) I'll mark you as the correct answer.