# Transform a permalink to a query in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess php Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564624/htaccess-php-rewrite)

I want to make redirect from page:

`http://www.bb.com/order/a`

to

`http://www.bb.com/order?val=a`

How can I make it?

UPD. User will ask server by first link, but response will be by second link.

UPD2.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^order/(.*)$ order?val=$1 [R, L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: no, may be using ".htaccess".
I want to get "val" by using $_GET["val"]

Comment: There are literally hundreds of other questions on how to map a URL segment to a query string parameter. Please do some research yourself before posting new questions.

Comment: I found solutions, but they don't work. That's why I posted a question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^order/(.*)$ order?val=$1 [R, L]
```

If you dont want to redirect but rewrite use `[PT, L]` instead of `[R, L]`

Comment: @Andrew I check if you have `mod_rewrite` `on`

Comment: shiplu.mokadd.im, where i should change this option? added .htaccess source. Did i make a mistake?